# Фильтрация названий столбцов по первым символам или по совпадению определенных символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, фильтрация

Анализирую Excel таблицу, в которой есть несколько листов, в заголовках которых, отличается только одно название ячейки. А именно: название ячейки "Дата пост.ф.1.2" отличается от названия аналогичной по содержанию ячейки в другом листе "Дата пост.ф.1" (в последней имя ячейки короче на 1 символ).

Пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd
sheet = input('Введите номер интересующей страницы: ')
sheet_result = 'Данные_' + str(sheet)
dd = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet_result)
result = dd.query('`Дата пост.ф.1.2`.notnull() == True') # фильтр ненулевых значений
print(len(result['Район']))
```

При выборе таблицы, в которой имя ячейки отличается от "Дата пост.ф.1.2" выдается ожидаемая ошибка:

```
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: 
name 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING_Дата_пост_DOT_ф_DOT_1_DOT_2' is not defined
```

Как сделать ***аналогичную конструкцию через метод `query()`*** (или в случае невозможности использовать указанный метод - альтернативный), где при выборе имени ячейки будет проверяться неполное совпадение по названию, а частичное, например "Дата пост" или "Дата пост.ф"?

Конструкции `if-else` не хочется применять, т.к. страдает гибкость и в случае изменения исходных названий ячеек возникнут проблемы.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query#pandas.DataFrame.query) не позволяет работать с именами столбцов, в которых встречаются символ точки или другие символы пунктуации или специальные символы.

В Pandas можно воспользоваться другими методами.

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   col 1  col 1.2  col 1.3  col 2  col2.1
0      3        4        4      1       9
1      1        7        0      0       0
2      7        7        2      2       0
3      4        3        0      1       5
4      0        7        9      5       5

In [16]: df.columns
Out[16]: Index(['col 1', 'col 1.2', 'col 1.3', 'col 2', 'col2.1'], dtype='object')
```

выбираем столбцы начинающиеся со строки `"col 1"`:

```
In [17]: df.columns.str.contains(r"^col 1")
Out[17]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False])

In [18]: df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r"^col 1")]
Out[18]: Index(['col 1', 'col 1.2', 'col 1.3'], dtype='object')

In [19]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(r"^col 1")]
Out[19]:
   col 1  col 1.2  col 1.3
0      3        4        4
1      1        7        0
2      7        7        2
3      4        3        0
4      0        7        9
```

Если нужен соответствующий DF (подмножество исходного DF с отобранными столбцами), то можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
In [20]: df.filter(like="col 1")
Out[20]:
   col 1  col 1.2  col 1.3
0      3        4        4
1      1        7        0
2      7        7        2
3      4        3        0
4      0        7        9

In [21]: df.filter(regex="^col 1")
Out[21]:
   col 1  col 1.2  col 1.3
0      3        4        4
1      1        7        0
2      7        7        2
3      4        3        0
4      0        7        9
```

выберем все столбцы содержащие точку в названии:

```
In [22]: df.filter(regex="\.")
Out[22]:
   col 1.2  col 1.3  col2.1
0        4        4       9
1        7        0       0
2        7        2       0
3        3        0       5
4        7        9       5
```